# R - data.table - Calculate average score of uniq-columns average scores

Tags: r, data.table, unique

Imagine a data table

```
ID    Score
1     10
1     13
1     12
2     10
3     6
3     6
```

The `average` of this table is  9.5.  That's easy enough to get using `mean`.

What if I wanted the average, of the average for each unique user?

The average for user 1 is 11.67.
The average for user 2 is 10.
The average for user 3 is 6.

The `UniqAverage` I am looking for would be `((11.67+10+6)/3) =`9.223`

This would be simple enough to do using a loop, but with my giant data set I want to continue my efforts to learn to do things the "proper" way in R making use of vectors.

We can even assume I already have a variable called Uniq that has in it the number of Uniq ID's, if that helps.

For replication purposes feel free to use...

```
library(data.table)
df = data.frame( ID=c(1,1,1,2,3,3), Score1=c(10,13,12,10,6,6) )
dt = data.table(df)
```

My failed attempt most recently was

```
mean( dt[ unique(dt$ID), Score1] )
```

I figured that would take the mean of Score1 for each ID, but it didn't quite work out. I got the result of `11.67` which is wrong.

Comment: I'd suggest that you go through the [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: Will do, thank you kindly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall mean:

```
dt[,mean(Score1)];
## [1] 9.5
```

Mean by ID:

```
dt[,mean(Score1),ID];
##    ID       V1
## 1:  1 11.66667
## 2:  2 10.00000
## 3:  3  6.00000
```

Mean of means:

```
dt[,mean(Score1),ID][,mean(V1)];
## [1] 9.222222
```

Comment: Fantastic! For the sake of learning, let me ask a brief question.  In the second block there, what exactly does that notation mean?  dt[ ,mean(Score1)] I take would mean return all rows, mean of Score1.  What does the ,ID do?  That seems like you're then using too many arguments.

Comment: The third argument `by` groups the input by one or more columns, meaning the second argument `j` will be evaluated once for each group. See the documentation at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf#page=4.

Comment: Thanks so much! Will accept your answer once the timer finishes.

Comment: Accepted. As a small extension, is it possible to do this only considering values with a Score1 value of greater than 10?  So, for example, in the case of ID=1, it would only take (13+12)/2, instead of (10+13+12)/3?

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
res <- dt %>%
        group_by(ID) %>%
        summarise(Mean = mean(Score1))
res
#    ID     Mean
#   (dbl)    (dbl)
#1     1 11.66667
#2     2 10.00000
#3     3  6.00000
```

Mean of means

```
res %>%
    .$Mean %>% 
    mean
#[1] 9.222222
```